# Unexpected scroll behavior after adding rows to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm a newbie just starting out with making my first apps without following along in a book or tutorial. I've created a simple app which, on launch, shows a UITableView with a single section which has a text field in the header and no rows initially. When you enter some text in the text field, it makes a web API call (fetching some JSON data from Wikipedia), then populates the table rows with the results of the call. Usually, there are enough results that the bottom of the table is no longer visible on the screen. All is well, until I try to scroll the table. When that happens, no scroll bar appears on the right edge of the screen, and the table doesn't move on a one-to-one scale with my finger movement. And when I release my finger, the table snaps back to the top so that the text field is again at the top of the screen - so basically it behaves the same way it behaves before there are any rows or few enough rows that they all fit on the screen. I *am* sending `reloadData` to the table view after the new data comes in - do I need to send it some other message to notify it that its size has changed or something?

EDIT: I've posted this same question over on MacRumors' forums, along with my project files. Please [give it a look](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=16273086) and download the project files if you think it can help you help me.

Comment: When you say "populates the table rows", what is actually happening in code?  (Normally, there's an array of some kind that provides data for the table.  If you add new objects to the array and call `reloadData`, it usually "just works"...provided your table data source methods are returning the right things.)

Comment: Yeah, I basically have an NSArray holding the data for the rows, and an implementation of `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which barfs out a cell for each corresponding item in the array. My `connectionDidFinishLoading:` implementation parses the fetched data and populates the data array with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove "use autolayout" from your WordsHeaderView nib file.
Click on the nib file, go in the "file inspector" and uncheck "use autolayout".
You have some autolayout constraints in the header view that "locks" the table scroll

Comment: I found the check box under the File Inspector pane instead of Identity Inspector, but after unchecking the box, everything worked as expected. Thanks, and enjoy your +50! I'll go do some research on just what that check box is doing so it doesn't stump me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In your WTAppDelegate.m change -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

to following

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    WordsViewController *viewController = [[WordsViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

then in WordsViewController.m comment the methods - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style and -(id)init and add the following method

```
-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView]; 
}
```

Comment: Why should I implement a UINavigationController if I don't need one? Is that just a standard practice or something? Also, won't that implementation of loadView just do the same thing as if it weren't implemented - that is, just call its super's implementation?

Comment: oh yes you are correct there is no need to add loadView method. The best practice is to use tableviewcontroller inside navigation controller. If you dont want to implement it than there is another alternative to add header inside table view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it as "viewForHeaderInSection", did you try setting it as "tableHeaderView". 
May be as follows.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.tableHeaderView = [self headerView];
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is it a standard or correct practice to set the header this way? It strikes me as hack-ish.

Answer (score 0):

In your WTAppDelegate.m change -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

to following

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
      WordsViewController *viewController = [[WordsViewController alloc] init];
      [[self window] setRootViewController:viewController];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;
}
```

comment out following methods from WordsViewController.m

1. -(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
2. -(id)init
3. -(UIView *)headerView
4. -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
5. -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

No need to add loadView method.

In WordsViewController.m add following to - (void)viewDidLoad

add

```
 wordsHeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WordsHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = wordsHeaderView;
```