# UITableView inside a Navigation Controller does not scroll after dismissing presentViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am showing a Modal Presentation View in a Navigation Controller by calling

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:controllerA animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And I am dismissing the controllerA by calling

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

After the dismiss is done the UITableView in in the previous navigationController does not scroll up and down where as it did before the presentViewController was called. Do I need to do something after dismiss to make the UITableView scroll again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a Header View in the UITableView and I needed to uncheck the "Use Autolayout" (in the File Inspector section) from the Xib file as I was loading the Header from a Xib.

[Unexpected scroll behavior after adding rows to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251297/unexpected-scroll-behavior-after-adding-rows-to-uitableview)